# Why is angularfire (afAuth.user | async) as user different than afAuth.user.subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am curious why the objects are different. I have a simple Angular component as follows:

**user.component.html**

```
  <pre *ngIf="(afAuth.user | async) as user"> {{ user | json }}</pre>
```

I used that so I can see what properties are on the user.

**user.component.ts**

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

  this.afAuth.user.subscribe(val => {
  console.log('user change', val);
  this.updateUserData(val);
});

}
```

However, the 'val' object returned in the subscription is different than what shows in the view. 
**Why is the object shown in the view different than what is returned from when I manually subscribe?**

My understanding is that the async pipe just subscribes for you. What am I missing?

I am asking because I would like to access the user.lastLoginAt and user.createdAt properties and store them in firestore.

In the view screenshot: 
[image: View Screenshot]

console.log(val) console screenshot:
[image: console screenshot]

Comment: could you add the two responses in your question, of what the `val` object is

Comment: Okay, added screenshots.

Comment: Please can you include the code where you are printed the val?

Comment: Updated, it's in the subscription.

Comment: did you try console.log(JSON.stringify(val))?

Comment: Yes, that makes it the same! Why is it different though?

Comment: Have you tried to cast `val` to `user` as you do in your template?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `async` in the template, you shouldn't have a `.subscribe` also in the template. What I suspect is that the template variable is the return of this method `this.updateUserData(val);`

You'll need to use the `tap` operator from `RxJS` to do anything that may have side effects.

```js
this.afAuth.user
  .pipe(
    tap((val) => {
      // any code in here will not change the `val`
      this.updateUserData(val);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log('user change', val);
  });
```

I will also suggest to create a reference of the service method in your class and use that in your template.

```js
@Component()
class UserComponent {
  authUser = this.afAuth.user;
}
```

---

Another thing to note is that the `| json` pipe calls the `toJSON` method on the object. So ...

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value is a function, then the toJSON() method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized. JSON.stringify() calls toJSON with one parameter:

There maybe a custom return on the `firebase.auth` object.

In your code; `user.lastLoginAt` and `user.createdAt` may actually be accessible in the template, but not visible in the `{{user | json}}` output.